# constant loss values with normal CNNs and transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am working on the dataset given in the paper https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1511/1511.02459.pdf
In this paper, a dataset of images (portraits of people) is labeled by a floating number between 1 and 5 (1 ugly, 5 good looking). I wanted to work on this dataset and use MobileNetV2 with transfer learning (pretrained on Imagenet) in Tensorflow 2.4.0-dev20201009 with CUDA 11.1 on my RTX 3070 8gb. I don't really see my mistake but training my model yields often in constant validation loss, for example:

```
78/78 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 52145660442.33472020-11-20 13:19:36.796481: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:596] layout failed: Invalid argument: Size of values 2 does not match size of permutation 4 @ fanin shape insequential/dense/BiasAdd-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer
78/78 [==============================] - 16s 70ms/step - loss: 51654522711.5709 - val_loss: 9.5415
Epoch 2/300
78/78 [==============================] - 4s 52ms/step - loss: 9.4870 - val_loss: 9.5415
Epoch 3/300
78/78 [==============================] - 4s 52ms/step - loss: 9.3986 - val_loss: 9.5415
Epoch 4/300
78/78 [==============================] - 4s 51ms/step - loss: 9.4950 - val_loss: 9.5415
Epoch 5/300
78/78 [==============================] - 4s 52ms/step - loss: 9.4076 - val_loss: 9.5415
Epoch 6/300
78/78 [==============================] - 4s 52ms/step - loss: 9.4993 - val_loss: 9.5415
Epoch 7/300
78/78 [==============================] - 4s 52ms/step - loss: 9.3758 - val_loss: 9.5415
...
```

The validation loss would remain constant for 300 epochs. My code can be found here below. Let me summarize:
I used transfer-learning from Imagenet and froze the convolutional base of MobileNetV2.
I added a dense layer as the classificator and 1 output neuron. The loss function I used is MSE. The optimizer in the code is SGD, and I also tried ADAM which could also yield constant loss values on the validation set.
The above error (constant val loss) occurs also with different learning rates and with ADAM. Sometimes the same learning rate yields not constant val loss but reasonable loss. I assume this is due to the randomized weights initialization method on the dense layers in my classificator. I even tried absurd learning_rates like 10, and values are still constant. If the lr is very high then changes should be clearly seen! This is not the case. What is wrong?

My code:

```
import os
from typing import Dict, Any
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import numpy as np
import cv2
import random

#method to create the model
def create_model(IMG_SIZE, lr):
  #Limit memore usage of GPU
  gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
  if gpus:
    try:
      tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(gpus[0], [
        tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024*7)])
    except RuntimeError as e:
      print(e)

  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(MobileNetV2(input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), include_top=False))
  model.layers[0].trainable = False
  model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.8))
  model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
  model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="relu"))
#use adam or sgd as optimizers
  adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98,
                                       epsilon=1e-9)
  sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=lr, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.5)
  model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
                loss=tf.losses.mean_squared_error,
                )

  model.summary()
  return model

#preprocessing
def loadImages(IMG_SIZE):
  path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data\\Images')
  training_data=[]
  labelMap = getLabelMap()
  for img in os.listdir(path):
    out_array = np.zeros((350,350, 3), np.float32) #original size of images in the dataset
    try:
      img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
      img_array=img_array.astype('float32')   #cast to float because to prevent normalization erros
      out_array = cv2.normalize(img_array, out_array, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) #normalize image
      out_array = cv2.resize(out_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) #resize, bc we need 224x224 for Imagenet pretrained weights
      training_data.append([out_array, float(labelMap[img])])
    except Exception as e:
      pass
  return training_data

#preprocessing, the txt file All_labels.txt has lines of the form 'filename.jpg 3.2' and 3.2 is the label
def getLabelMap():
  map = {}
  path = os.getcwd()
  path = os.path.join(path, "data\\train_test_files\\All_labels.txt")
  f = open(path, "r")
  for line in f:
    line = line.split()
    map[line[0]] = line[1]
  f.close()
  return map

#not important, in case you want to see the images after preprocessing
def showimg(image):
  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  plt.imshow(image)
  plt.show()

#pickle the preprocessed data
def pickle_it(training_set, IMG_SIZE):
  X = []
  Y = []
  for features, label in training_set:
    X.append(features)
    Y.append(label)
  X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
  Y = np.array(Y)

  pickle_out = open("X.pickle", "wb")
  pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
  pickle_out.close()

  pickle_out = open("Y.pickle", "wb")
  pickle.dump(Y, pickle_out)
  pickle_out.close()

#for prediction after training the model
def betterThan(y, Y):
  Z=np.sort(Y)
  cnt = 0
  for z in Z:
    if z>y:
      break
    else:
      cnt = cnt+1
  return float(cnt/len(Y))

#for prediction after training the model
def predictImage(image, model, Y):
  img_array = cv2.imread(image)
  img_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  img_array = np.array(img_array).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
  y = model.predict(img_array)
  per = betterThan(y, Y)
  print('You look better than ' + str(per) + '% of the dataset')

#Main/Driver function
#Preprocessing
IMG_SIZE = 224
training_set=[]
training_set = loadImages(IMG_SIZE)
random.shuffle(training_set)
pickle_it(training_set, IMG_SIZE) #I pickle my data, so that I don't always have to go through the preprocessing

#Load preprocessed data
X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
Y = pickle.load(open("Y.pickle", "rb"))

#Just to check that the images look correct
showimg(X[0])

# define the grid search parameters, feel free to edit the grids
batch_size = [64]
epochsGrid = [300]
learning_rate = [0.1]

#save models and best parameters found in grid search
size_histories = {}
min_val_loss = 10
best_para = {}

#ignore this, used for bugs on my gpu... You possibly don't need this
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True))
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)


#grid search, training the model
for epochs in epochsGrid:
  for batch in batch_size:
    for lr in learning_rate:
      model = create_model(IMG_SIZE, lr)
      model_name = str(epochs) + '_' + str(batch) + '_' + str(lr)
      #train the model with the given hyperparameters
      size_histories[model_name] = model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=batch, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)
      
      # save model with the best loss value
      if min(size_histories[model_name].history['val_loss']) < min_val_loss:
        min_val_loss = min(size_histories[model_name].history['val_loss'])
        best_para['epoch'] = epochs
        best_para['batch'] = batch
        best_para['lr'] = lr
        model.save('savedModel')



#If you want to make prediction
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("savedModel")
image = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data\\otherImages\\beautifulWomen.jpg')
predictImage(image, model, Y)
```

EDIT:
I have found the issue. It is 'relu' in the output neuron. When I change my loss from RMSE to MAPE I will see that I got a 100 percent error on validation. I assume this is because all my validation data is output to 0. This is only possible when the value in the output neuron before 'relu' is negative. I don't know why this is the case. But removing 'relu' will yield better training.

Does anyone know why 'relu' causes this problem with regression problems?

Comment: Have you tried `CategoricalCrossentropy`?

Comment: isnt that for one-hot encoded vectors? My labels are real values in the interval [1,5].

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed the `is labeled by a floating number between 1 and 5` part while reading.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your last layer

```
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="relu"))
```

then your models final output is `y if y > 0 else 0`.  At your untrained state, your model could very well have y pinned to something like -17 or 17 with fairly equal chance.  In the case of -17, the *relu* will convert that to 0 and also set the gradient to 0, which means the network doesn't learn.  Yeah, the network doesn't learn anything from any part of a network where a relu unit output 0.  In the case of the layer before

```
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
```

there will be a really good chance that about half of the units will fire with a positive value and so they learn, so that layer is fine.

What can be done in the case of a bad initialization or after training a bad state in which the output of that last layer is pushed down to below 0?  Well, what if we just don't use *relu*.  What activation to use?  None!  Let's look at what that would be

```
1: model = keras.Sequential()
2: model.add(MobileNetV2(input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), include_top=False))
3: model.layers[0].trainable = False
4: model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
5: model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.8))
6: model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
7: model.add(layers.Dense(1))
```

Lines 1-6 are all the same.  It is important to note that the output of line 6 passes through the non-linear relu activation, and so there is the capability to learn non-linearities.  Line 7, without an activation function will be a linear combination of Line 6, with a full ability to generate gradients in the positive and negative output region.  When backprop is applied to learn the target values of 1 to 5, if the network outputs -17, it can learn to output a larger number.  Yeah!

If you'd like to have 2 layers of nonlinearity, I'd suggest the following

```
1: model = keras.Sequential()
2: model.add(MobileNetV2(input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), include_top=False))
3: model.layers[0].trainable = False
4: model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
5: model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="tanh"))
6: model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="tanh"))
7: model.add(layers.Dense(1))
```

Ditch the dropout unless you have actual proof that it helps *in this very specific network* (and right now I suspect you don't).  Try *tanh* as your hidden layer activation function.  It has some nice features, like being positive and negative, gradient even with large and/or negative numbers, and acts somewhat to automatically regularize weights.  But, importantly, the last output either has no activation function.